# Match a multi-level URL in Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to set up my `urls.py` file so that it can process the following url:

http://localhost:8000/project/path/**level1/level2/level3**

The desired outcome is to go to `path` view and pass a parameter containing the entire highlighted path ("level1/level2/level3").

I have tried 
`urlpatterns = [
url(r'^path(/(?P<url_path>[-\w]+)?){0,8}$', views.path, name='index')
];`

However this only works for 1 level, i.e.

http://localhost:8000/project/path/**level1** will work

http://localhost:8000/project/path/**level1/level2** won't work

Comment: Did you read this? =) 
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/urls/#using-regular-expressions

Comment: `^path(/(?P<url_path>(?:[-\w]+/){0,8})$` ?